# Create Mnemonic using react-native and BIP39 is not working

Tags: mnemonic, bip39

I tried to generate mnemonic for my react native application using Both BIP39 and react-native-Bip39 and it is working fine in the simulator but as soon as I try to generate a mnemonic on a physical device it is failing with a console error that say that it is only supported on browser such as chrome or Firefox, is there another library, a fix or another way to make this library run on react native?

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yes i did!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the issue is that react's library is old, it wasn't updated for 5 years and encryption has evolved since plus weaknesses found in old libraries.

There's a fork that updated this library to use native pbkdf2 from react-native-aes-crypto, there's a pull request but it wasn't merged yet.

react-native-bip39 fork: https://github.com/annakaz/react-native-bip39

Side note: **code review this package for yourself**, as a malicious actor could modify it so it'll produce a pseudo-random seed, which he has access to.

Comment: i found a solution, not sure if you want but i can send you the repo, my code is open source

Comment: sure, add it here for others

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [@medardm/react-native-bip39](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@medardm/react-native-bip39) package. It works well on my side.